# Struts2 jquery jqgrid dynamic drop list while grid edit

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, grid

this is my jsp code.

```
<s:url id="myEditOptions" action="myEditOptions.action"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="branch" align="left" index="Branch" id="bnch" title="Branch" 
    editable="true" onclick="" edittype="select" editoptions="%{myEditOptions}"  />
```

**struts.xml code**

```
<action name="myEditOptions" class="com.example.action.BranchAction" method="getDynamicBranch">
    <result name="success" type="json" ></result>
</action>
```

**Actionclass code here**

```
public class BranchAction implements Action {

    private Map<String, String> branchList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    List<Customer> customerList;
    private List<String> brnch;
    Struts2ExampleDAO exampleDao ;
    private String myEditOptions;
    public BranchAction() {
        exampleDao = new Struts2ExampleDAOImpl();
        customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    }

    public String getDynamicBranch(){       
        customerList = exampleDao.getCustomerListData();
        brnch = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Customer cust:customerList) {
            int i=0;
            if(cust.getBranch() != null && cust.getBranch().length() !=0) {             
                brnch.add(""+i+":"+cust.getBranch());
            }
            i++;

        }
        //Collections.sort(brnch);
        myEditOptions = "{value:'"+StringUtils.join(brnch,";")+"'}";
        System.out.println("************List size:::********"+brnch.size());
        return "success";
    }


    public String getMyEditOptions() {
        return myEditOptions;
    }

    public void setMyEditOptions(String myEditOptions) {
        this.myEditOptions = myEditOptions;
    }
}
```

branch dropdown list is not displaying. If anybody knows please help me to get dynamic drop list while grid edit using struts2 jquery **jqgrid**. Even i can able to get dynamic drop list by using normal struts2 select option

```
<s:select label="What's your favor search engine" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines"
    list="searchEngine" 
    name="yourSearchEngine" />
```

Like this i need same functionality(dynamic dropdownlist) while doing struts2 grid edit select option

Answer (score 0):

oops! yup finally got solution toget dynamic drop down list while editing grid using struts2 jquery jqgrid and made the following changes working fine now.!

```
public String getDynamicBranch(){       
    customerList = exampleDao.getCustomerListData();
    myEditOptions = "<select>";
    for(Customer cust:customerList){
        if(cust.getBranch() != null && cust.getBranch().length() !=0) {
            System.out.println("******Branch values***:::"+cust.getBranch());
            myEditOptions += "<option value="+cust.getBranch()+">"+cust.getBranch();
        }

    }
    myEditOptions += "<select>";
    //Collections.sort(branchList);     
    return "success";
}
```